# PHP: does include dirname(__FILE__).'/../libs/somelibt.php'; use APC caching?

Tags: php, include, apc, include-path

From a file located on `/A/a.php` I need to include a file located on `/B/b.php`

Since a.php is included by files from different directories on different nesting levels I cannot use

```
include '../B/b.php';
```

(`../B/` will be relative to the file including `a.php` and not `a.php` location)

So the best solution I have right now is to use  (on `a.php`)

```
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../B/b.php';
```

so that b is accessed relative to a.php.

This works but I have a feeling that APC wont cache `b.php` because the include statement requires calling `dirname(__FILE__)` and is not static.

Am I right? What's the best way to solve this?

Note:I cannot use document_root since its different on the dev server and production server.

Thanks !

Comment: maybe use `__DIR__` instead for `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: @Orangepill Same thing

Comment: I'm fairly certain that using `dirname(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__` will resolve to an absolute path before APC becomes involved. APC should be receiving the full paths

Comment: @Phil you are probably right ... I just figured __DIR__ would be more likely because it would be evaluated at parse time as opposed to execution time.

Comment: @Orangepill too true. I like `__DIR__` better anyway

Comment: I just learned that `dirname(__FILE__)` was used before `__DIR__` was introduced in PHP5.3 so I'll use `__DIR__` instead. Since its not dynamic the APC issue is solved.
Thanks for the answeres !